# how to observe data change in a separate component in react-query?

Tags: react-query

I am trying to make one component aware of the update of another using react-query. I tried the way to achieve this using UseMutation and QueryCache but wasn't successful.
I think this would work if there is a way to receive pull dataset after refetch(). Is this possible with react-query?

```js
//App.js
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
    </QueryClientProvider>

//ComponentA.js
const ComponentA = () => {
  const { data,refetch } = useQuery("data A", () =>
    fetch("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?key=8364626")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => res)
  );

  const fetchData = () => {
    refetch();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => fetchData()}>fetch data A</button>
    </>
  );
};


//ComponentB.js
const ComponentB = () => {
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery("data B", () =>
    fetch("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity?key=8364626")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => res)
  );

  const fetchData = () => {
    refetch();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => fetchData()}>fetch data B</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that react-query can deduplicate queries for you based on the query key you provide.

```
function ComponentA(props) {
  useQuery(['queryKeyA'], () => {})
}

function ComponentB(props) {
  useQuery(['queryKeyA'], () => {})
}
```

Those two components use the same query identified by `['queryKeyA']` so if one component forces a refetch and the data change, the other component will also get the update.

In you code, your problem is that you use two different query keys, so the two queries are distinct and cannot be synced without too much hassle.

--

Bonus, your queries are not really returning any data because you do the final `.then((res) => console.log(res))` so it returns `undefined`, but I guess that's just because you wanted to simplify the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I'm looking for is to use context or redux toolkit to share a dynamic query key and eventually any dynamic data (that will be processed in a custom useXXXXXXXX hook like the one you can read [here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations)

And then use the hook and the shared dynamic key, so you will recall the hook like:

```
const data = useCustomDataQuery(['queryKeyA', dynamicParams], () =>{})
```

then treat dynamicParams like you'd do with any shared state manager like RTK or useContext